# php login doesnt redirect on server

Tags: php, authentication, redirect

I have one problem in PHP. I have my webpage with login. When I try to login on localhost after writing email and password and hitting login it redirects me to dashboard. But when I upload my page to hosting and I am trying to do that online, it doesn´t redirect me at first, I have to refresh or login one more time to redirects me. How could I fix it? Thanks.
Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();


if (isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_name'])){
    header('Location: dashboard/index.php');
}

?>

 <?php



            if (isset($_POST['login'])){
                $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
                $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];



                try{
                    include 'dashboard/includes/db.php';


                    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :user_email AND user_password = AES_ENCRYPT(:password, :key)";


                    $send_info = $connection->prepare($query);

                    $send_info->bindParam(':user_email', $user_email);
                    $send_info->bindParam(':password', $user_password);
                    $send_info->bindParam(':key', $key);

                    $send_info->execute();


                    $send_info->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $result = $send_info->fetchAll();

                    if(count($result) == 0){
                        $message = "<h6 class='text-danger mt-2'>Chybný email alebo heslo</h6>";
                    }
                    else{
                    
                        foreach ($result as $item){
                            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $item->user_id;
                            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $item->user_email;
                            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $item->user_name;
                            $_SESSION['user_lastname'] = $item->user_lastname;
                            $_SESSION['user_role'] = $item->user_role;
                            $_SESSION['user_function'] = $item->user_function;
                            $_SESSION['user_image'] = $item->user_image;

                            header('Location: dashboard/index.php');
                            exit;
                        }
                    
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception $e){
                    echo $e;
                }

            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not like the ?> (empty space) <?php part. Outputting anything before a header() call will have unintended consequences. Also you miss an exit() after the first header.

Comment: yes, the empty space surely may cause the observed result in certain server.

Comment: Thanks!! It really helped.